# XSLT Transformation based on predefined output string

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, xslt

I need xslt to transform, My Xml is as below

```
 <OrderReferences>
            <OrderRef>
              <OrderRef>OrderRef1</OrderRef>
              <Type>ERP</Type>
            </OrderRef>
            <OrderRef>
              <OrderRef>OrderRef2</OrderRef>
              <Type>CUSTOMER</Type>
            </OrderRef>
            <OrderRef>
              <OrderRef>OrderRef3</OrderRef>
              <Type>EXT</Type>
            </OrderRef>
          </OrderReferences>
```

My Output from this should be

```
<OrderReference> (OrderReference for ERP should appear here) </OrderReference>
<OrderReferenceCustomer> (CustomerReference for Customer should appear here) </OrderReferenceCustomer>
<OrderReferenceExternal> (ExtReference for EXT should appear here) </OrderReferenceExternal>
```

Let me know if this is achievable. XSLT 1.0 version preferrable as i want this for .Net. Thanks.

Comment: Where in the original XML do you have `CustomerReference` and `ErpOrderReference`?

Comment: ErpOrderReference, ErpCustomerReference, ErpExtReference are the objects where i want to put these data to. 

I need an xslt some thing like this.
<ErpOrderReference> <xsl:value-of select="OrderRef\Type='ERP'"/> </ErpOrderReference>

Comment: Well, the correct answer is "yes, it's achievable". Don't you think you should try it yourself and come back if you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="OrderRef[Type='ERP']">
     <OrderReference><xsl:value-of select="OrderRef"/></OrderReference>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="OrderRef[Type='CUSTOMER']">
     <OrderReferenceCustomer><xsl:value-of select="OrderRef"/></OrderReferenceCustomer>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="OrderRef[Type='EXT']">
     <OrderReferenceExternal><xsl:value-of select="OrderRef"/></OrderReferenceExternal>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<OrderReferences>
    <OrderRef>
        <OrderRef>OrderRef1</OrderRef>
        <Type>ERP</Type>
    </OrderRef>
    <OrderRef>
        <OrderRef>OrderRef2</OrderRef>
        <Type>CUSTOMER</Type>
    </OrderRef>
    <OrderRef>
        <OrderRef>OrderRef3</OrderRef>
        <Type>EXT</Type>
    </OrderRef>
</OrderReferences>
```

**produces the exact wanted, correct result (unlike the currently accepted answer):**

```
<OrderReference>OrderRef1</OrderReference>
<OrderReferenceCustomer>OrderRef2</OrderReferenceCustomer>
<OrderReferenceExternal>OrderRef3</OrderReferenceExternal>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of the **xsl:element** to create new element names based on the **Type** element. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="OrderRef">
      <xsl:element name="Erp{substring(Type, 1, 1)}{translate(substring(Type, 2, string-length(Type) - 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}Reference">
         <xsl:value-of select="OrderRef" />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<OrderReferences>
   <ErpErpReference>OrderRef1</ErpErpReference>
   <ErpCustomerReference>OrderRef2</ErpCustomerReference>
   <ErpExtReference>OrderRef3</ErpExtReference>
</OrderReferences>
```

This should cope with **Type** elements containing any value.

Comment: I need xslt for version "1.0", as .net doesnt support functions such lower-case .

Comment: I've changed it to be XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your inputs, really helpful.

Comment: Here is the resultant outcome. Thanks every one for their inputs.

<xsl:template match="OrderReferences">
<xsl:for-each select="OrderRef">
<xsl:if test="Type='ERP'">
<OrderReference>
<xsl:value-of select="OrderRef"/>
</OrderReference>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="Type='CUSTOMER'">
<OrderReferenceCustomer>
<xsl:value-of select="OrderRef"/>
</OrderReferenceCustomer>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="Type='EXT'">
<OrderReferenceExternal>
<xsl:value-of select="OrderRef"/>
</OrderReferenceExternal>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>